# Check if any file was downloaded in Paramiko recursive file transfer

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm not able to figure out why cannot get exit code 1 in this function when `item` or `item.filename` which is the absolute path to file is empty ?

```
def sftp_get_recursive(path, dest, sftp):
    item_list = sftp.listdir_attr(path)
    dest = str(dest)
    if not os.path.isdir(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
    for item in item_list:
        mode = item.st_mode
        if not str(item) :
           print(item.filename)
           print("No file found")
           sys.exit(1)
        elif S_ISDIR(mode):
           sftp_get_recursive(path + "/" + item.filename, dest + "/" + item.filename, sftp)
        else:
           sftp.get(path + "/" + item.filename, dest + "/" + item.filename)
           print("Sending file from : ",path + "/" + item.filename)
           sftp.remove(path + "/" + item.filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return specific exit code, if there is no file anywhere in the directory tree, you will have to recursively count the files.

```
def sftp_get_recursive(path, dest, sftp):
    count = 0
    item_list = sftp.listdir_attr(path)
    if not os.path.isdir(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
    for item in item_list:
        source_path = path + "/" + item.filename
        dest_path = os.path.join(dest, item.filename)
        if S_ISDIR(item.st_mode):
           count += sftp_get_recursive(source_path, dest_path, sftp)
        else:
           print("Sending file from : ", source_path)
           sftp.get(source_path, dest_path)
           sftp.remove(source_path)
           count += 1
    return count
```

*(I have refactored your code a bit to avoid repeating code)*

And then use the count at the top level:

```
count = sftp_get_recursive(path, dest, sftp)
if count == 0:
    print("No file found")
    sys.exit(1)
```

*Note that even if no files are found, the code will still recreate the empty remote directory structure locally. I'm not sure, if that's what you want.*